# Ruby, conversin to string

Tags: ruby, string

I wrote this program in ruby:

```
"Nonna = CIAO CARO NIPOTINO, COME STAI??"
 puts "Tu = Bene nonna, ma non urlare"
 puts "Nonna = COME DICI, PARLA PIU' FORTE!!"

def ask()
    a = gets.chomp
    ok = a.upcase()
    numero = rand(100)
    ciao = "CIAO NONNA!"
    if a == ok
       puts "NO CARO, NON LO VEDO DAL " + numero
       ask
    else
       puts "COSA HAI DETTO? NON CI SENTO, RIPETI!"
       ask
    end
end

ask()
```

(Excuse the Italian)
However, when I run it it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from vecchia.rb:20:in `<main>'
    1: from vecchia.rb:11:in `chiede'
vecchia.rb:11:in `+': no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Now that your question has been answered I suggest you submit your corrected code to SO's sister-site, [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There you will get suggestions on how to improve you code. (There are several problems, the main one being that you should not use recursion here.) That site is tasked with helping you to improve working code, whereas SO is concerned with broken code and algorithmic issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's complaining about a number concatened to a string. Two simple ways

1) turn the number into a string

```
puts "NO CARO, NON LO VEDO DAL " + numero.to_s
```

or 2) interpolate the number into the string

```
puts "NO CARO, NON LO VEDO DAL #{numero}"
```